# Magento 2 - How to install a new currency?

Tags: magento2

I get following error message when I try to add a new currency,

```
Selected allowed currency "US Dollar" is not available in installed currencies.
```

[image]

Comment: set base currency as US Dollar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to app/code/Magento/Directory/etc/config.xml and check the `default/system/installed/currency` node. It's the default place where Magento 2 stores installed currencies configuration. By default, all currencies available in the "Allowed Countries" list are installed. The are two common  reasons why you can get such issue:

- The installed currencies value is modified in app/code/Magento/Directory/etc/config.xml
- Some custom extension is overridding the installed currencies value. Check all your custom extensions for etc/config.xml file and ensure that these files don't have `default/system/installed/currency` node inside.

Comment: Thank you for the help but It didn't work.

/var/www/html/magento/vendor/magento/module-directory/etc/config.xml seems intact. 

I did while card search for <currency> node using follwing command.
grep --include=config.xml -rnw '/var/www/html/magento' -e "<currency>"

I don't see any config.xml file wich contains <currency> node  other than the file you module-directory/etc/config.xml.

Comment: Well then, try to check your database table `core_config_data`. Ensure that you don't have a record with path `system/installed/currency` there.

Comment: Ooops! I do have, Should I delete it or change the value of it?

Comment: Just remove the record and you will have the default set of currencies installed. But, as usual, make the database backup first.